# Guardar en txt salida de consola al ejecutar script

Tags: python, lista, ssh, log, telnet

Hola quiero guardar log de todo lo que se ejecuta  el script, o sea, mi caso es el siguiente:
Me conecto por ssh/telnet a equipos vía modulo paramiko donde primero con la función print(" me conecto a device5") visualizo el equipo a conectarme y luego  ejecuto los comandos sobre el equipo conectado y lo que quiero es guardar un log file (ya sea .log .txt)  tanto los print()  como las  respuestas de los comandos ejecutados, básicamente quiero guardar todo lo que veo que se va ejecutando en 'Consola' cuando corro el script.

dejo ejemplo de mi script:

```
import paramiko
import time
host = 10.62.23.14
print (f"\n{'#'*50}\n Conectando a device {host} \n{'#'*50}")
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, username='pass', password="pass")
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
chan = ssh.invoke_shell()

for command in commands: # tengo los comandos en una lista y los recorro
        
        data = chan.send(f'{command}\r')
        time.sleep(0.2)
        while True:
           data = chan.recv(1024)
           output = data.decode('ascii').split(',')
           print (''.join(output)) # visualizo en consola la respuesta de los comandos ejecutados 
           if (b"BASE TRANSCEIVER STATION HANDLING") in data:    
               break
               print("####SALE DEL BUCLE####")
    ssh.close(
```

espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya muchas gracias... saludos

Edito:

Estuve  haciendo pruebas y obtengo el log buscado realizando lo siguiente desde shell cmd ejecutando:   C:>   python mi_script.py > log.txt

quisiera poder obtener los mismo "pero" con código ya implementado en el propio script para poder ejecutarlo desde mi IDE Spyder, poder visualizar en consola y que guarde el log.

espero  haya sido mas claro en lo que  busco, desde ya gracias nuevamente... saludos

Comment: ¿Es necesario que los mensajes continuen apareciendo en pantalla?, es decir, se guardan en un archivo pero sin aparecer en la consola.

Comment: ¿Has considerado utilizar alguna biblioteca para log y hacerlo _manual_ o quieres que todo lo que vaya a la salida estándar vaya al archivo?

Comment: antes gracias por su pronto respuesta, @SergioC me siento mas cómodo viendo en consola lo que se ejecuta y posterior  verlo en el archivo log guardado.

Comment: @jachguate intente ocupar el modulo logging pero no logre entenderlo hacerlo funcionar,  solo necesito lo que visualizo  en consola se guarde en el log  nada mas por el momento pero estoy abierto  a consejos y opiniones al respecto, gracias

Comment: ¿Y tu pregunta es sobre como usar el modulo logging, o como redireccionar la salida de `print` a un archivo?

Comment: @jachguate la pregunta es como puedo guardar un log de lo que veo en consola cuando ejecutó mí script,  utilizando ya sea el módulo logging u otra forma/método de obtener lo que necesito, estoy abierto a propuesta ya que no sé cómo hacerlo, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manera correcta de hacerlo es mediante un módulo de logging. Python 3 cuenta con un módulo de logging dentro de sus paquetes estándar, es decir que no es necesario realizar una instalación extra.

Un programa que redireccione la salida hacia un archivo(output.txt) y hacia la salida estándar(stdout) se definiria de la siguiente manera:

```py
import logging
import sys

FILENAME_LOGGING = 'output.txt'
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler(FILENAME_LOGGING))

# Programa
# ...
# En vez usar print, usar logger.info
logger.info('Test de salida...')
```

### Partes del programa

Se define un objeto logger y se configura su nivel. El nivel hace referencia a un nivel de tipo de mensajes, por ejemplo, existen los niveles DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, etc. Si tu defines como nivel del logger a DEBUG, todos los mensajes de ese y todos los niveles superiores van a ser capturados, es decir, van a ser mostrados en la terminal o en el archivo de salida. En caso de elegir a INFO como el nivel, los mensajes de niveles inferiores (DEBUG) no van ser capturados.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

En un segundo paso, se define los handler. Los handler son simplemenete funciones que van a recibir los mensajes capturados por el logger y van a realizar algo con esos mensajes. En nuestro caso queremos 2 handlers, uno que persista el comportamiento natural de mostrar los logs en pantalla, es decir un `StreamHandler` que tenga como flujo de salida la salida estándar(sys.stdout) y un segundo handler que imprima los mensajes en un archivo que se refleja como un `FileHandler` que apunta al archivo con nombre `FILENAME_LOGGING`.

```py
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler(FILENAME_LOGGING))
```

Una vez configurado el logger, podemos imprimir mensajes a través de él con los métodos debug, info, error, etc... Cada método hace referencia a uno de los niveles a los cuales se hizó referencia anteriormente en la configuración, es decir, que debemos configurar correctamente el logger para que los mensajes que esperamos capturar realmente sean capturados. Generalmente un print imprime información informativa sobre la ejecución del programa, razón por la cual su método equivalente seria info.

```py
# Programa
# ...
# En vez usar print, usar logger.info
logger.info('Test de salida...')
```

Logging cuenta con muchas otras configuraciones y utilidades, te recomiendo dar un vistazo a la [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) y a este [artículo](https://realpython.com/python-logging/).

**Nota.** El handler `StreamHandler` por defecto abre el archivo en modo `a`, es decir que en caso de existir información en el archivo, esta va ser respetada y la nueva información va ser agregada al final del archivo. Para forzar a sobrescribir el contenido cada vez que sea iniciado el programa, solo es necesario agregar de manera explícita el modo a `w`, resultando en: `logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler(FILENAME_LOGGING, mode="w"))`

### Otras formas

Existen otras formas de obtener un resultado parecido al anterior y van desde redireccionar la salida estándar a través de la terminal, hasta sobrescribir la función print de la siguiente manera...

```
import sys

FILENAME_LOGGING = 'output.txt'
with open(FILENAME_LOGGING, encoding='utf-8', mode='w') as file:
    def custom_print(*args):
        sys.stdout.write(' '.join([*args, '\n']))
        file.write(' '.join([*args, '\n']))

    print = custom_print

    print('Log 1')
    print('Log 2')
    print('Log 3')
```

La única ventaja es que puedes seguir utilizando la función print, sin embargo esta implementación no soporta todos los argumentos extra que la función print normal soporta y no suele ser una solución muy elegante. No recomiendo esta solución pero es bueno tener conocimiento de varias opciones.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta @SergioC lo probé pero no me funciono! solo me guarda la ultima línea logger.info('Test de salida...') en el output.txt

Comment: En el caso de tu implementación, solo habría que modificar cada `print` por `logger.info`. Como menciono en la explicación, print general es utilizado para mostrar mensajes informativos, en ese caso lo más correcto es usar el método `info` del logger, que esta justamente enfocado en ese tipo de mensajes.

Comment: excelente @SergioC  ahora si!  mala mía... me falto eso justamente reemplazar los print por logger.info()....  gracias por tu tiempo.. saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el módulo `logging`. Un ejemplo muy simple sería:

```
def main():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='log.log', level=logging.INFO)

    logging.info('Empieza el log')

    logging.info('Mensaje para el log')

    numero = 5
    if a != 5:
        logging.info('[!] El numero no es igual a 5')

    logging.info('Termina el log')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Más info del módulo en [documentación logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html). Tienes muchas opciones para personalizarlo como quieras. `:)`

Comment: muchas gracias @Fran me fue de utilidad... saludos gracias por tu tiempo...